# Understand shell script

Tags: jvm, zsh, openhab

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in caseta.crt -inkey caseta.key -out caseta.p12 -name caseta

keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore lutron.keystore -srckeystore caseta.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass secret -alias caseta

keytool -importcert -file caseta-bridge.crt -keystore lutron.keystore -alias caseta-bridge
```

I need help understanding this script that adds these files into keycert so that I can edit the script with the correct file names?

Comment: The first word in each line is the name of the program being executed (`openssl` and `keytool`). The rest of the lines are the parameters. For understanding what the programs do with the parameters, do i.e. a `man openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

1º) openssl pkcs12 -export -in caseta.crt -inkey caseta.key -out caseta.p12 -name caseta

> This command will create the file **caseta** in format PKCS12(PFX), from the private key(caseta.key) and certificate(caseta.crt)

2º) keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore lutron.keystore -srckeystore caseta.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass secret -alias caseta

> It will import the file p12 **caseta.p12** and store on **lutron.keystore** for Java to use.

3º) keytool -importcert -file caseta-bridge.crt -keystore lutron.keystore -alias caseta-bridge

> It will import the certificate **caseta-bridge.crt** and store on lutron.keystore for Java to use.